# Unexpected keyword UNION in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to run a UNION query like this:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
    s.campaign_name, 
    date(event_date) as event_date,
    'email' medium,
    count(s.send_id) sends
    from pixel_logs.table1 s
    inner join pixel_logs.full_logs AS l on l.uid = s.uid
    where 1=1
    group by
    event_date,
    campaign_name
    order by
    event_date

UNION ALL

    select
    s.campaign_name,
    date(event_date) as event_date,
    'sms' medium,
    count(s.send_id)
    from pixel_logs.table2 s
    inner join pixel_logs.full_logs AS l on l.uid = s.uid
    where 1=1
    and account_id = 'xxxx'
    group by
    event_date,
    campaign_name
    order by
    event_date;
```

But I'm getting this message:

```
Syntax error: Unexpected keyword UNION at [21:1] Dismiss
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `UNION` queries `ORDER BY` is typically applied once, at the very end, and not to each portion of the query.  You can try removing `ORDER BY` from the first half of your query:

```
#standardSQL
select
    s.campaign_name, 
    date(event_date) as event_date,
    'email' medium,
    count(s.send_id) sends
from pixel_logs.table1 s
inner join pixel_logs.full_logs AS l on l.uid = s.uid
    where 1=1
group by
    event_date,
    campaign_name

UNION ALL

select
    s.campaign_name,
    date(event_date)
    'sms' medium,
    count(s.send_id)
from pixel_logs.table2 s
inner join pixel_logs.full_logs AS l on l.uid = s.uid
    where 1=1
    and account_id = 'xxxx'
group by
    event_date,
    campaign_name
order by
    event_date;
```

Also, you should not need any aliases in the second half of the `UNION` query, as the aliases assigned in the first half are what will be used.